# Rails 3: tricky one... refresh select box after modal without reloading the entire page

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a new highly tricky question that is driving me nuts since 3 days now... Maybe somebody could help me with this.

I have a view with a selectbox (for the user to choose an account):
here is a part of the view:

```
div id="boxplot">
<div id="box1">
Sur quel compte?<br />
<div id="banque"><%= render 'banque', :f => f %></div><br /><br />
Combien?<br />
<%= f.text_field :montant %>
</div>
```

Then here is the partial:

```
<%= f.select(:debit, @in.collect {|p| [p.nom, p.numero]} + ['Ajouter...'], {:include_blank => 'Sur quel compte?'})%>
```

As you can see I have a variable in the controller new action that is:

```
def new
@journal = Journal.new
@in = Compte.where(:categorie => "Actif")
```

Is have implemented a modal box to give the user the possibility to "add a new account" (compte is of course another model). Here is the Javascript. It's simple, just check if the user select "Ajouter..." and if yes open a iframe to create a new record in the compte model:

```
$(function () {
$('#banque').change(function() 
{
$a = $('#journal_debit').val();
if ($a == "Ajouter...") {
$.fancybox({
        'width': '70%',
        'height': '70%',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'scrolling': 'no',
        'padding': 45,
        'showCloseButton': true,
        'title': "Ajouter un nouveau compte" ,
        'titleShow': true,
        'titlePosition': 'over' ,
        'onComplete': function() { 
        $("#fancybox-title").css({'top':'0px', 'bottom':'auto'}); 
        },
        'href': '/comptes/modal/'
    });
}
else
{
}

});
})
```

I submit this request with js with create.js.erb:

```
$(function () {
parent.$.fancybox.close();
})
```

Everything works fine to this point but coming back to the parent form, my select box is not updated (I mean the new created account is not displaying in the select  box...).

Only way to get it is to add this one to create.js.erb:

```
parent.location.reload(true);
```

But the problem is that reloading the whole page will loose the data the user would have inputed before triggering the modal box...

I can't find a way to do this tricky one. Is it possible to reload only a part of the page (for example the partial that includes the select box) but if yes how to refresh the @variable?

Or is there another cool way to achieve what I'm after?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple change to your HTML, so you might as well use JS to do it - especially since you're using a JS callback already.  Adding something like

```
$('#select-box-id').append(
    '<option value="<%= @company.id %>"><%= @company.name %></option>'
);
```

to your callback function should do all the basics for you.  Check out the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for more details - they're a good general reference, too.

Cheers!

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea but when I implement it @company is not including the new company created from the modal...

Comment: How could I handle to "reload" the @variable after having created a new records via the modal?

Answer (score 1):

Hi everybody and thanks for your inputs it helped me a lot in finding the solution.

I've resolved this one adding this Ajax call in the onClosed trigger of the fancybox :

```
'onClosed': function() {$.getScript("/entrees/new.js"); },
```

So this one is calling a new.js.erb file when the modal box is closed. In this file I've managed to insert the new *compte* entry into the selectbox. This is the /new.js.erb

```
$('#journal_debit > option:last-child').before(
'<option value="<%= @in.last.numero %>"><%= @in.last.nom %></option>'
);
```

Mission accomplished!